# Different models for different level TreeView nodes

Tags: python, treeview, pygobject

Let's say I have a TreeView (with a backing TreeStore) that represents a list of products.

A Product has the following specifications:

1. Name
2. Catalog Number
3. Comment

Also, each product has a list of Components that it is constructed of.
I want to display data about the components in the sub-nodes of the tree (so it would be, basically, a 2-level treeview), but then the top-level nodes will have a different model the the sub-nodes.

How can I accomplish it using Glade (Or if neccessery, through Python+PyGObjecy)?

Comment: I think you can, maybe by mapping each CellRenderer visibility to another column in the model. But the exact way to do it depends on how your presentation need to be. Can you wireframe a TreeView as you want it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one model per TreeView, but you can make a model that in realty are two (or more) models glued together, and add some boolean columns that controls which model should that line be displaying. Then, you add a set of CellRenderers and map it's visibility to those control columns.

The difficulty of this is when you want that the column had a name displayed on the top, in that case it can be difficult to order the information. If you can wireframe how you want the Tree to look like I can offer a base example implementation.

== EDIT ==

This is one example:

**main.py**:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

WHERE_AM_I = abspath(dirname(__file__))

# My Model map
mm = {
    'name'        : 0,
    'catalog_num' : 1,
    'comment'     : 2,
    'component'   : 3,
    'is_top'      : 4,
    'is_child'    : 5,
}

class MyApp(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Build GUI
        """

        # Build GUI from Glade file
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.glade_file = join(WHERE_AM_I, 'gui.glade')
        self.builder.add_from_file(self.glade_file)

        # Get objects
        go = self.builder.get_object
        self.window = go('window')
        self.treestore = go('treestore')

        # Fill model
        self._load_model()

        # Connect signals
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)
        self.window.connect('delete-event', lambda x,y: Gtk.main_quit())

        # Everything is ready
        self.window.show()


    def _load_model(self):

        my_data = [
                ['Cheese', 'F001', 'This is the best cheese ever!', '', True, False],
                ['Pepperoni', 'F002', 'Delicious pepperoni :}', '', True, False],
                ['Pepperonni Pizza', 'P001', 'Yes, I\'m hungry :(', '', True, False],
                ['', '', None, 'Cheese', False, True],
                ['', '', None, 'Pepperonni', False, True],
            ]

        parent = None
        for i in my_data:
            if i[mm['is_child']]:
                self.treestore.append(parent, i)
            else:
                parent = self.treestore.append(None, i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui = MyApp()
    Gtk.main()
```

**gui.glade**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
  <object class="GtkTreeStore" id="treestore">
    <columns>
      <!-- column-name name -->
      <column type="gchararray"/>
      <!-- column-name catalog_num -->
      <column type="gchararray"/>
      <!-- column-name comment -->
      <column type="gchararray"/>
      <!-- column-name component -->
      <column type="gchararray"/>
      <!-- column-name is_top -->
      <column type="gboolean"/>
      <!-- column-name is_child -->
      <column type="gboolean"/>
    </columns>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="border_width">10</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">TreeView test</property>
    <property name="window_position">center-always</property>
    <property name="default_width">400</property>
    <property name="default_height">300</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="shadow_type">in</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkTreeView" id="treeview">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="model">treestore</property>
            <property name="headers_visible">False</property>
            <property name="headers_clickable">False</property>
            <property name="search_column">1</property>
            <property name="tooltip_column">2</property>
            <child internal-child="selection">
              <object class="GtkTreeSelection" id="treeview-selection"/>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn_name">
                <property name="title" translatable="yes">Name</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="cellrenderertext_name"/>
                  <attributes>
                    <attribute name="visible">4</attribute>
                    <attribute name="text">0</attribute>
                  </attributes>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="cellrenderertext_component"/>
                  <attributes>
                    <attribute name="visible">5</attribute>
                    <attribute name="text">3</attribute>
                  </attributes>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn_catalog_num">
                <property name="title" translatable="yes">Catalog #</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="cellrenderertext_catalog"/>
                  <attributes>
                    <attribute name="visible">4</attribute>
                    <attribute name="text">1</attribute>
                  </attributes>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Code can also be found at: https://gist.github.com/carlos-jenkins/5555283